# How do I reference an element of an "unamed" array?

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

I'm using laravel 5.6, and the debugbar allows me to do this:

```
 $IncomingAJAX = json_decode($AJAXrequest, TRUE);
 Log::info($AJAXrequest);
```

which produces this:

```
[2018-08-05 20:39:11] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'category' => 'This is Category 1',
    'answers' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'question' => 'This is Question 1',
        'score' => 2,
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'question' => 'This is question 2',
        'score' => 3,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'category' => 'Category #67',
    'answers' => 
  ...
```

But how do I refer to a specific element? This is driving me mad. I've tried `Log::info($AJAXrequest[0].category[0].Answers[0]);` and `Log::info($IncomingAJAX[0].category[0].Answers[0]);` or even just `Log::info([0].category[0].Answers[0])` or this one `Log::info(AJAXrequest['category'])` to no avail.

But this works: `Log::info($AJAXrequest[0]['category']);`

What I'd really like to do is iterate as follows:

```
$jsonIterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new \RecursiveArrayIterator($AJAXrequest),
                \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
...}
```

I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your syntax is incorrect. you are accessing array elements. The dot (.) syntax is invalid in PHP.

Try

```
$AJAXRequest[0]["category"]
$AJAXRequest[0]["answers"][0]["question"]
$AJAXRequest[0]["answers"][1]["question"]
$AJAXRequest[1]["category"]
...
```

You need to look into the structure of your array more.

Also, seems like `$AJAXRequest` is already an array, so no need for `json_decode()`

Comment: Thank you. That nested array. 'Answer' is as the same level as 'category'. Grrrr.

Comment: But I still don;t understand why this test fails: `if(is_array($AJAXrequest))` ... php tells me it's not an array.